# Add read more to the_content

Tags: the-content, custom-post-type-archives, read-more

Hi I have a custom post type that i've truncated on the archives pages using this:

```
function limit_the_content($content){
  $word_limit = 35;
  $words = explode(' ', $content);
  return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit));
}
```

How would I add a read more and a link to the end of each post.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a link manually like:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID) ?>">Read More...</a>
```

If you want to add the link at the end of the content you could do:

```
return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit)) . '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">Read More...</a>';
```

Comment: Ha awesome. I added this just after I posted. Thanks :)

Comment: If this answered your question, could you hit the check mark at the left side the answer?